# Can we increase MTSUser validity?

Tags: active-directory, users

Our Content Manager Tridion uses a Windows account "MTSUSer" which gets expired in every 90 days, then we request windows team to reset the password as we do not have admin rights in production. Is there any way we can increase the password expire window for MTSuser.

Can this be solved some other way?

Comment: There is an option "Never Expire" in the User properties. Ask your Windows Admin to check that checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the Windows team disable the password reset requirement - we often highlight that this is not a user account but a **system** account which is often dealt with differently.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thansk @Dylan .. Mark Saunders , is this anywhere mentioned in SDl Docs ?

Comment: I suspect it's not documented by SDL as this is an OS/System configuration. SDL requires a system account with specific privileges, how you manage those is down to DevOps/ITSec etc.

Comment: There's some info here https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-91951F46-2020-4F8C-8B55-B91C2F317DDD but as Mark says, it's not explicit as it falls beyond the scope of the Content Manager and more into an organization's practice and rules for System/Service accounts.